Hypothesis test based on coefficient vs based on likelihood ratio, in the presence of correlated covariates?
I have timeseries data from a quasi-experiment (Condition: Baseline vs Intervention, applied blockwise in an ABAB pattern), but since the situation is not well controlled I also have a number of observed covariates corresponding to possible confounds. The covariates are correlated among themselves as well as with the manipulation.
I have set up a linear model for this, if you will a 1-way 2-level ANCOVA, except that possible autocorrelation of errors is modeled as AR(1). (in R using gls from nlme)
What confuses me is that the p-values differ between

a test for the coefficient of the Condition dummy regressor vs 0, $p = 0.0019$ from $t(70) = 3.235616$, and
a likelihood ratio test between models with and without the regressor, $p = 0.0002$ from $F(1, 70) = 15.1067$.

(using summary and anova, respectively)
I understand that the two tests work differently: One is based on the coefficient estimate and its standard error in the full model, while the other compares the variance accounted for by the full and reduced models. I believe that without covariates (being correlated with Condition), the two should be equivalent ($F = t^2$), but with correlated covariates the Condition regressor in the full model picks up variance which to some degree can also be picked up by the covariates in the reduced model.
But I'm still confused, because both tests seem to have the same null hypothesis ("no effect of Condition"). Is the difference a matter of statistical power?
More importantly, the different p-values make it possible that one of them is below the conventional significance level and the other isn't. If so, which one should I use to declare "a statistically significant effect of Condition"?
Also, is it possible to make a general statement which of the two p-values will be (stochastically) smaller?
Apart from a direct answer, I would also appreciate literature pointers or relevant keywords for a search.
